# На дату события или в результате события

Tags: значение-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, грамотное обоснование довода о том, что повреждения на дату ДТП включают в себя все имеющиеся повреждения на автомобиле на момент ДТП, в том числе полученные ранее в результате других ДТП.

Comment: Если сказать "повреждения на момент ДТП", то не понятно включаются ли повреждения полученные в момент ДТП или нет. Можно сказать "повреждения на момент регистрации ДТП"

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо именно **обосновать**? Не найти формулировку, а истолковать где-то имеющуюся - в каком-то документе, скорее всего?!
Мне кажется, это невозможно *обосновать*. *Толкование смысла - вообще не наша задача,* а тут еще юридическая составляющая, юристы верят только себе и суду.
Так что тут может идти речь только об *экспертной оценке такого смысла*. В каком-то смысле мнение эксперта - и есть обоснование. Ну есть ещё такая вещь как правоприменительная практика. В вашем случае можно сослаться на то, что данную формулировку так понимали всегда, да и по логике оно так. При оформлении ДТП, например, да и в других ситуациях, установить "на месте", когда какие повреждения были нанесены, почти невозможно. Поэтому всегда оформляют по факту. Что видно - то и пишут.
Иначе никак.

А с чем вообще связан такой вопрос? Никогда бы не подумал, что доказывать подобные самоочевидные вещи - вопрос актуальный.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за ответ. Ситуация, скорее, обратная общепринятой, в связи с этим и такой вопрос. В 2019 году имело место быть мелкое ДТП - автомобили столкнулись бамперами, в результате чего оба автомобиля получили легкие повреждения этих самых бамперов. Прибывшие на место ДТП сотрудники ГИБДД указали повреждения: бампер задний, бампер передний. Пострадавший автомобиль 2002 года выпуска, весь битый-перебитый, приобретенный владельцем за 140 000 руб. С меня решением суда взыскана сумма ущерба более 200 тыс. Как такое оказалось возможным?

Comment: В обоснование иска приложено экспертное заключение на эту самую сумму более 200 тыс, в котором помимо бампера заднего указаны: фара задняя, глушитель, панель задка, крыло заднее, лонжерон задний, арка крыла и т.д. и т.п. А вопрос, поставленный на рассмотрение эксперта и, соответственно, выводы экспертизы звучат как: "Определение стоимости восстановительного ремонта авто на дату ДТП (а не в результате ДТП)". Решением суда с виновника мелкого ДТП, в котором пострадал лишь бампер авто взыскана вся заявленная сумма. Поэтому могли бы поподробнее подсказать про правоприменительную практику?

Comment: P.S. Мной была проведена трасологическая экспертиза, которая полностью опровергла возможность получения заявленных к возмещению материального ущерба повреждений именно в результате данного ДТП.

Comment: @Виктория боюсь, я вас невольно излишне обнадежил, упомянув правоприменительную практику. Я абсолютно не в курсе конкретики. Имел в виду лишь то, как юристы толкуют сочетание "на день такой-то (ДТП - в нашем случае)". Если речь идет о какой-то конкретной фразе, попавшей в документ, то просто приведите её. Если нет, то не заморачивайтесь, а найдите формулировку, исключающую подобное.

Comment: Хотя судя по всему, вам надо просто указать в кассации/апелляции (адвокат поймет, что именно), что суд, как вы и объяснили мне, неправомерно включил в сумму ущерба, причиненного виновником ДТП, ущерб от повреждений ТС, которые имелись НА момент ДТП, а не полученные в результате самого ДТП. Мне совершенно очевидно, что иное толкование слов эксперта "НА ДАТУ" невозможно. Да эксперт-оценщик и не компететен решать вопросы о том, когда именно были насены повреждения.

Comment: Случайно знаю, что в практике зарубежных юристов часто используется очень емкое латинское выражение Post hoc, ergo propter hoc ("после" не значит "вследствие"). Возможно оно вам пригодится при рассмотрении апелляции. Повреждения имеющиеся на ТС **после** ДТП не могут трактоваться как полученные **вследствие** ДТП. Это вообще не вопрос о том, как трактовать фразу эксперта. Это общий принцип, суд, если все так, как вы описали, явно совершил грубейшую ошибку.